# Three tiered CSS menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to make a three tiered CSS style menu.

Jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/kBVYD/1/

What I need to accomplish is to have the third tier of the menu to stay aligned with the parent menu. When you hover over menu item A, Menu B dropsdown. When you hover over the menu items in the dropdown they show a third dropdown to the right of Menu B.

Right now the third menu (products) when hovered is floating to the left, and it should be droping down under the initial menu item.

```
     <div class="full_width">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="page-wrap">           
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
                                <ul class="sub_menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Compliment Containers<span class="span_right">&raquo;</span></a>
                                         <ul class="test">
                                            <div class="menu_level3_01">
                                                <span><a href="#">Wastebaskets</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Compost</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Curbside</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Deskside Recycling</a></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="menu_level3_02">
                                                <span><a href="#">Large Trash Collection</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Large Reycling Collection</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Waste Streaming Containers</a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
                                <ul class="sub_menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Compliment Containers<span class="span_right">&raquo;</span></a>
                                         <ul class="test">
                                            <div class="menu_level3_01">
                                                <span><a href="#">Wastebaskets</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Compost</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Curbside</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Deskside Recycling</a></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="menu_level3_02">
                                                <span><a href="#">Large Trash Collection</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Large Reycling Collection</a></span>
                                                <span><a href="#">Waste Streaming Containers</a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how this is supposed to look. Do you have  a design image?

Comment: As I mentioned below, a hover menu with vertically expanding sub-menus is not really usable (just look his fiddle and try to select the 2nd and 3rd menu options of the first drop down). There are a couple workarounds: 1) You could use JavaScript to have the menu not collapse until after the user has moved their cursor back into it and then out of the drop down, or 2) You make the menu click activated, where options expand and collapse on click rather than hover. Both of these however break users expectations on how menus usually work

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the second tier relative and left: 0.

```
    #menu1 ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li ul
{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    left: 0%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kBVYD/34/

Comment: You'll want to consider the implications of moving the sub-lists below their parents, as opposed to beside. In the fiddle, its impossible to get to the 2nd and 3rd menu items on the first drop down.

Comment: I realise that, but that wasn't the question

Comment: Well my comment is partially directed at the OP, but your answer is still broken; it isn't effective and obviously doesn't accomplish a result the OP can use

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kBVYD/36/)

You need the parent of the last menú (the "li") to NOT have position relative so the last menu absoluted position won't depend on the parent.

The as you have fixed values it's easy to set the submenu right where you want with 5px top (the margin of the first submenu with the main menú and the just a value for the left position, in this case 180px).

basically I've just added this to the fiddle:

```
.sub-menu > li {position:static !important;}
.sub-menu ul {top:5px !important; left:180px !important; }
```

Edited: the !important is just to overwrite your css's in the fiddle. You may better implement this attributes insteed of the others for a cleaner css sheet.